# Software/service for email marketing

Tags: email, newsletter, marketing

I am looking for a professional email marketing service or software.

I have a small company and  send about 10 emails per year, all in 6 months period and my mailing list is about 1000 emails long and growing.

Features that I want in my software/service:

- Scheduled mailings
- duplicated emails check and;
- some sort of spam check/proofing.

Since I do not send a lot of emails I am guessing that a one time buy of software would be better for me compared to subscribing to a service. Are there any downsides with using software compared to a service?

I looked into a few programs, and 3 meet my demands:

- [SendBlaster](http://www.sendblaster.com/);
- [GroupMail](http://group-mail.com/) and
- [e-Campaign](http://www.lmhsoft.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm wondering why you just look for a desktop-application or a paid web-service?!?

**IMHO the best would be your own web-service!** - therefor i never tried something like and have no experiences with the solutions you mentioned... but the advantages are obvious:

- you are platform independent, just a browser is needed
- you are device independent; you can also accomplish some tasks in your holidays with your smartphone or even a public surf-station
- you are not restricted or charged by messages and/or subscribers
- you don't have to hand over your costumers data to a third party
  ***HINT:*** in some countries you are not allowed to do so, if they not explicitly allowed you to do so.

---

the concrete software i can recommend is [**phpList**](https://www.phplist.org/):

- it is foss under AGPL, therefor it is free of charge and if you lack some functions you are allowed to extend it in every possible way
- multilingual, translated into 30+ languages
- you can import/export, manage and organize your subscribers
- subscribers can opt-out and opt-in by themselves and also update their own data and subscription preferences
- mails can be personalized and written as text and html
- you can use and manage several templates
- decide exactly how you handle bounces
- campaigns can be scheduled
- analyze your campaigns with inbuilt statistics
- and you can try a demo at: http://demo.phplist.org/lists/admin/

and at the end, if you have a website with with more than just a simple html-site, i bet you have already [everything you need](https://resources.phplist.com/system/start) (*AMP-server) to run phpList.

if you need help with the manual installation, they also provide a very detailed [tutorial on their site](https://www.phplist.org/manual/ch028_installation.xhtml).

Comment: I will not be using the service myself. It has to be as simple for use as possible. 
I am not computer illiterate, have done some web programming in the past, but I do not have any experience with email web services at all.
I am sure i am able to learn how to set it up. 
My question: when I set it up (php list), is it user-friendly?

Comment: Oh I kind of get it now.. It is an application, like WordPress and even the install process is similar.
So I just install it on my server and from there on it shouldn't be too difficult for anybody to use?

Comment: @MartinPeternel: the best thing would be to test it yourself with the demo linked in my answer: just enter the suggested login, choose your language and you are ready to go...

Comment: @MartinPeternel: well... from the technical point of view most of these web-services/-apps are similar: they need a [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_(software_bundle))-server and that's it... **;-)** after that some need more and difficult configuration, some not to finish the setup.

Comment: If I install phpList , I am guessing I have to configure my campaigns so that there are not too many mails going out per hour/day, since most servers have limitations in that way?

Comment: @MartinPeternel: maybe yes... but for possible restrictions and that you not abuse the server, you have to ask/talk to your hoster.

Comment: What about installing a server with SMTP on my PC, and install phpList on it.
Would I then be restricted only with my bandwith? Would it even work?

Comment: @MartinPeternel: this should be possible... for further assistance please consult the resources, manuals, community, forum, etc. on https://www.phplist.org/. -- but i wouldn't advise you to do that! you will either lose the advantages of a web-service respectively face a few inconveniences or have to run your server/pc 24/7; and considering your questions i would NOT run a public server 24/7 on your own.

Answer (score 3):

Look into [Mail Chimp](http://www.mailchimp.com) and specifically at their Free package.  You can have 2,000 subscribers and send 12,000 emails per month for free. No need to purchase anything at all.

I have not used any of the programs you mentioned, so I don't know what advantages they do / don't provide.  The obvious disadvantage to those programs is the one-time buy when in fact you don't have to spend any money at all.

Comment: Seconded. I've used Mail Chimp for small campaigns. One nice advantage is that their templates take care of device independence for you.